# Adding user to secondary group not showing in id -Gn

Tags: users, group

I have added my user to the users group using the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G users foo
```

However, when I then type the `id -Gn` command it is not showing the user as being part of the users group. I then try the following and it says it is apart of the users group:

```
getent group | grep users
```

Also tried simple id foo command and says it is part of it as well. Why is it not showing in my secondary groups when I use `id -Gn`?

Comment: Also noticed it shows up when I specify the user name. Using 'id -Gn foo' displays the right groups but 'id -Gn' doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are logged as 'foo' when issuing the command 'id -Gn' ? given your explanation and first comment, this could explain that the group appears only when typing 'id -Gn foo'

Comment: type 'whoami' to see if you're actually logged in as foo